# Verbs before "pedagogical value"?

Tags: verbs

Is the sentence "The thing has pedagogical value" idiomatic? I am not sure what to put before "pedagogical value".

Comment: what exactly you want? *something has pedagogical value* is fine.

Comment: Ah, yes. That is what I want! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *[something] has* pedagogical value.... -is fine

There's nothing wrong with it.

A sentence from a book

> The interactive strategy ***has pedagogical value.*** Placing a test point at a node with the...